# How do I remove root node from json?

Tags: c#, json

I have a json from an Api response that looks like this:

```
Data: {
  "PrinterIp": "192.168.111.11",
  "PrinterPort": 9100,
  "Template": "standard",
  "LabelInfo":{
    "FirstName": "john",
    "LastName": "doe",
    "ReqNum": 123123123,
    "DateOfBirth": "2020-01-01"
  }
}
```

How do I remove the root node? When I try to select everything in that node using select token it doesn't seem to work because it's not a valid json property that is in quotes.

var token = JToken.Parse(json).SelectToken("data");

How do I get just this:

```
{
  "PrinterIp": "192.168.111.11",
  "PrinterPort": 9100,
  "Template": "standard",
  "LabelInfo":{
    "FirstName": "john",
    "LastName": "doe",
    "ReqNum": 123123123,
    "DateOfBirth": "2020-01-01"
  }
```

Comment: The API response is not valid JSON.

Comment: Is `Data:` in the response?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove first characters:

```
json = json.Substring(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const jsonStr =
    '{"Data":{"PrinterIp":"192.168.111.11","PrinterPort":9100,"Template":"standard","LabelInfo":{"FirstName":"john","LastName":"doe","ReqNum":123123123,"DateOfBirth":"2020-01-01"}}}';

  const json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  const newJSON = json.Data;
  console.log(newJSON);
  // or if you don't know the exact key but you want to get the root
  const root = Object.keys(json)[0];
  console.log("get root", json[root]);
```